# Returning response message from self hosted web service and is it soap?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

Currently I have this small client:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyService.CalculatorClient ws = new MyService.CalculatorClient();

            ws.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();

            ws.xml("<DOCUMENT></DOCUMENT>");

            ws.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Which works fine it basically just sends a string to my web service and I generate an xml and store it somewhere.

I would like to get back the response though, if I use WCFTestClient.exe I see this response.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples/ICalculator/xmlResponse</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:325d2f97-c1f0-4b66-912a-d9b3a6b097a7</a:RelatesTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <xmlResponse xmlns="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples">
      <xmlResult>Success</xmlResult>
    </xmlResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I would like to return this to my client console app and display it. However, I am having a hard time getting it to display. I made the string public at the web service but not able to return it.

My other question is...if SOAP is just xml is my web service a soap service I haven't declared it to be so what defines it being SOAP or how do I turn it into SOAP. Here is my app.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
          <security mode="None">
            <message establishSecurityContext="false"/>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

SOAP is mentioned in the beginning of the response, does this mean this is a soap connection even though I didn't establish it or configure it to be?

Thanks any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to display some message in client side send by wcf sevice?

Comment: The binding in your configuration is 'wsHttpBinding' it is SOAP 1.2 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind

Comment: @Vinoth The service gives back a response like the one posted above I would like that to be displayed on my client console application

PrasanthVJ ah ok thanks!